# how do you parse from XML using yq?

Tags: xml, yq

Hi I would like to parse the servers names using yq the problem is that I have to specify the index of each server every time i wounder if the is a method to get the servers names without specifying the index using yq or any other methods.

```
╭─hakimimap in ~/notes on main ✘ (origin/main)
╰$ cat /home/hakim/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/base_domain/original/config.xml | yq -p=xml .domain.server
- name: AdminServer
  ssl:
    name: AdminServer
    listen-port: "7002"
  listen-address:
- name: Server_1
  machine: Machine_1
  listen-port: "7003"
  cluster: Cluster_1
  listen-address:
  jta-migratable-target:
    user-preferred-server: Server_1
    cluster: Cluster_1
- name: Server_2
  machine: Machine_1
  listen-port: "7004"
  cluster: Cluster_1
  listen-address:
  jta-migratable-target:
    user-preferred-server: Server_2
    cluster: Cluster_1
- name: Server_3
  machine: Machine_1
  listen-port: "7005"
  cluster: Cluster_1
  listen-address:
  jta-migratable-target:
    user-preferred-server: Server_3
    cluster: Cluster_1
```

Comment: Could you please provide a minimum sample of `config.xml` so the question complies with a [mcve]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass a query to request the info. In this case `'.domain.server[] | .name'` will get server names

```
# multiple servers
yq -o 'y' '.domain.server[] | .name' config.xml
# single server
yq -o 'y' '.domain.server | .name' config.xml
```

For some version around v4.35.x of `yq` below command would throw a warning

> 12:14:03 initCommand [WARN] yq default output is now 'auto' (based on the filename extension). Normally yq would output 'xml', but for backwards compatibility 'yaml' has been set. Please use -oy to specify yaml, or drop the -p flag.

```
yq -p xml '.domain.server[] | .name' test.xml
```

Result

```
AdminServer
edys-web
```

From `yq` help

> -p, --input-format string
> -o, --output-format string          [auto|a|yaml|y|json|j|props|p|xml|x|tsv|t|csv|c] output format type. (default "auto")

`yq -oy ...` is  a bit confusing to me as in some command it could mean `cmd -o -y`, so

```
yq -o 'y' ...
yq -o 'yaml' ...
yq --output-format 'y' ...
```

:-)

Comment: Does not work for me. I get this error: jq: Unknown option -p
Use jq --help for help with command-line options,
or see the jq manpage, or online docs  at https://jqlang.github.io/jq
yq: Error running jq: ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed in this context

Comment: @MarioVilas The utility is [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) not `jq`.

Comment: seems like `-p` flag is now deprecated


`initCommand [WARN] yq default output is now 'auto' (based on the filename extension). Normally yq would output 'xml', but for backwards compatibility 'yaml' has been set. Please use -oy to specify yaml, or drop the -p flag.` so the command should be now:

`yq -oy '.domain.server[] | .name' test.xml`

Comment: @Titou thanks. Do you have a link to document the deprecation? Couldn't find anything myself

Comment: @LMC seems like it has been released on version https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/tag/v4.32.1. For information, I am on verison: `version v4.40.2`